# Haxe - how can I pass generic class to parameter

Tags: generics, parameters, haxe

```
function test(cls:Class<Dynamic>) {}

test(Array<Float>); // Unexpected )
```

I have to pass `Array<Float>` as the class type. However, this fails with:

> Unexpected )

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible, similar to how you can't explicitly specify the type parameter of a function when calling it ([see here](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3666)). You can just pass `Array` instead:

```
test(Array);
```

One way to get that to compile is by using a `typedef`:

```
typedef FloatArray = Array<Float>;

test(FloatArray);
```

However, `Class<T>` doesn't really care about the type parameters of `Array`, so there's no point to doing that:

```
typedef FloatArray = Array<Float>;
typedef IntArray = Array<Int>;

trace(FloatArray == IntArray); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
@:generic
private function test<T>(type:Class<T>) { 

}
```